# Ansible set_fact not working at all for my task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.8
```

I believe this is a different issue from [Ansible's `set_fact` not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379608/ansibles-set-fact-not-working-at-all).

I have the following variable defined in `group_vars/all.yml`

```
nexus_repo = "dev_builds"
nexus_url = "https://nexus.company.com/{{ nexus_repo }}"
```

Then on one of my tasks, I do

```
- name: Adjust nexus_repo value for release builds
  set_fact:
    nexus_repo: "release_builds"
    nexus_url: "https://nexus.company.com/{{ nexus_repo }}"

- debug: msg="{{ nexus_url }}"
```

When I run my playbook (`my-playbook.yml` runs `my-role.yml`), I just see

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inverntories/hosts.yml -e var_hosts=my-host my-playbook.yml

TASK [my-role : Adjust nexus_repo value for release builds] ****************
ok: [10.227.x.x]

TASK [my-role : debug] *****************************************************
ok: [10.227.x.x] => {
    "msg": "https://nexus.mycompany.com/repository/dev_builds"
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: `group_vars/all.yml` is not valid YAML format. Should be `nexus_repo: "dev_builds"` and `nexus_url: ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't re-use variables declared in the same *set_fact*. For example, if the variables *nexus_repo* and *nexus_url* are declared for the first time in the *set_fact* below. The task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        nexus_repo: release_builds
        nexus_url: "https://nexus.company.com/{{ nexus_repo }}"
```

will fail because *nexus_url* can't use *next_repo* declared at the previous line:

> The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'nexus_repo' is undefined

This explains the 'strange' behavior you see when the *group_vars/all.yml* is used

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
nexus_repo: dev_builds
nexus_url: "https://nexus.company.com/{{ nexus_repo }}"
```

The *set_fact* below will use the value *dev_builds* of the variable *nexus_repo* from *group_vars/all.yml* when evaluating *nexus_url*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        nexus_repo: release_builds
        nexus_url: "https://nexus.company.com/{{ nexus_repo }}"
    - debug:
        var: nexus_url
```

gives

```yaml
  nexus_url: https://nexus.company.com/dev_builds
```

There are more options on how to fix it. For example, don't declare the same variable *nexus_url* twice

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        nexus_repo: release_builds
    - debug:
        var: nexus_url
```

gives

```yaml
  nexus_url: https://nexus.company.com/release_builds
```

If you have to declare *nexus_url* new put it into the separate *set_fact*. For example, the tasks below give the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        nexus_repo: release_builds
    - set_fact:
        nexus_url: "https://nexus.company.com/{{ nexus_repo }}"
    - debug:
        var: nexus_url
```

See the Ansible issue [Can't reference a dict key inside the same dict #50280](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280).